# Visual Leak Detector not showing stack trace

Tags: visual-leak-detector

I'm getting a memory leak report from Visual Leak Detector without a stack trace.

```
---------- Block 9961 at 0x000000000A27EE40: 128 bytes ----------
  Leak Hash: 0x9C7787F5, Count: 1, Total 128 bytes
  Call Stack (TID 4408):
  Data:
    D0 1C 16 0A    00 00 00 00    D0 26 35 0A    00 00 00 00     ........ .&5.....
    20 1E 16 0A    00 00 00 00    90 22 15 0A    00 00 00 00     ........ ."......
    90 1B 35 0A    00 00 00 00    50 32 15 0A    00 00 00 00     ..5..... P2......
    70 2A 15 0A    00 00 00 00    40 21 15 0A    00 00 00 00     p*...... @!......
    50 1C 35 0A    00 00 00 00    20 22 15 0A    00 00 00 00     P.5..... ."......
    A0 2C 15 0A    00 00 00 00    F0 3B 15 0A    00 00 00 00     .,...... .;......
    B0 1C 35 0A    00 00 00 00    20 29 15 0A    00 00 00 00     ..5..... .)......
    30 33 15 0A    00 00 00 00    30 2C 15 0A    00 00 00 00     03...... 0,......
```

I'm using the version of VLD from here: [https://github.com/oneiric/vld/releases/tag/v2.7.0]

I tried using the safe stack trace but that just resulted in the code running very slowly but no difference in the output.

What can I do to get the call stack displayed for this memory block?

Is this the correct version of VLD - there seem to be a few around!!???

Comment: Does anyone know?